# How to use the Windows Keystore (MCS) with JDBC?

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, oracle11g, jsse

I am trying to create a java application that uses `PKI` for authentication. I need to be able to retrieve a certificate from the Microsoft Certificate Store (MCS) and pass it along to an Oracle database (11.2).

I am connecting using the `jdbc:oracle:thin` driver. After spending quite some time on google I have come up empty. 
I've found different properties to change (depending on the article):

- set the property `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType = "Windows-MY"`
- set the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore = "Windows-MY"`
- `javax.net.ssl.keyStore should be set to "None"` (if using a custom KeyManager which I do not believe will work since by the time it gets into my custom KeyManager I will already be given the certs from a keystore specified in the connection properties).

Of course all of these people are claiming success, but nothing has worked for me. I have tried every example I have been able to find all with no luck.  I was able to successfully authenticate when I was using Oracle wallets so I know my certificates are fine. If anyone has done this before and is willing to post some code that would be great.

I know most people are using the Windows keystore with a website and therefore are creating their own SSLContext, but I cannot imagine I am the only one who has wanted to do this using JDBC (which as far as I know does not allow me to provide it an SSLContext).

This is the code that I believe should work, but does not.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver)new OracleDriver());
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=host)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=someName))(SECURITY= (SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN=\"CN=TESTSERVER\")))";

java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "Windows-MY");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "NONE");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "Windows-ROOT");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "NONE");

props.setProperty("oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match", "true");
props.setProperty("oracle.net.authentication_services", "(TCPS)");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

This code fails with the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IOException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 3):

[This article ("*Leveraging Security in the Native Platform Using Java SE 6 Technology*" by Valerie Peng, October 2006)](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/security.html) should give your more details. Although it doesn't use the system properties, `Windows-MY` is clearly a store type and it's not file based. Therefore, `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` should be `Windows-MY` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` should be set to `NONE` (upper case may matter), see the [JSSE Ref Guide (Customization)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization):

> `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` system property
>
> Note that the value NONE may be specified. This setting is appropriate if the keystore is not
> file-based (for example, it resides in a hardware token).

You may also need to configure your trust store in a similar way if your server certificate isn't trusted by your default Java trust store.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have read both articles, but still am not having any luck.  I have modified my original post with the code I have tried and with the current error message.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the driver didn't follow the JSSE Ref Guide for this in the JDBC driver implementation. If you can (and if it doesn't disturb the rest of your application), I'd try to set the `javax.net.ssl` properties as global system properties, and leave these JDBC properties empty: the JDBC driver is likely to use the default `SSLSocketFactory` in this case.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work.  I noticed that I am not getting any debug output from `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL");` So it doesn't seem to be getting very far in the handshake process.

Comment: Alas, after all this time, link is dead.

Comment: @GrahamLeggett I've just updated it